# Is there a "special" URL param to force SWFObject to show alt content?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, url

I remember doing this years ago, but can't remember if it was with `SWFObject`.
Anyone heard of this before?
I guess it would basically disable `SWFObject` from switching the `altContent` for the `SWF`.

I though it was something like:

```
www.mysite.com?noflash=true
```

But can't remember the real one (if it exists).

Thanks

Comment: just JS onload handler which will check all embedded objects for flash and control them over JS processor.

Comment: Seems like there is a way to force the Flash content to load (using the url param `detectflash=false`), but not force the alt content to load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built in way to do this with swfobject that I know of, but you can manually do what you want fairly simply.

```
<script>
if (location.href.indexOf('noflash=true') !== -1) {
    swfobject.embedSWF = function () {};
}
swfobject.embedSWF("test.swf", "flash", "300", "250", "9.0.0");
</script>
```

You're just checking if "noflash=true" exists in the URL. If it does, make swfobject.embedSWF an empty function.

If the parameter doesn't exist, swfobject embeds the SWF as usual.